# Jquery ajax $.post() method issue in safari with Primefaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, primefaces

Did jquery ajax `$.post()` method work in Safari 3.2.3 (525.29) or other?

I am trying to get some information dynamicly when user types on an input but It seems to doesn't work.

Also, in other Safari versions (I just tested on version 5) this is working good and also IE and others.

Could anyone confirm to me this or give me more information regarding `$.post()` with Safari or maybe information or issues about jquery library from primefaces?

I will really appreciate your opinions.

**EDITED**

I am using jquery library with primefaces and I have the following, just an example or code snippets:

```
// 1. I imported a base64.js that has this structure: (This .js is obfuscated for security)

// methods situated at base64.js
var key = "b3NjYXJqY";


    function base64key(){
        this.key = function(){
            return key;
        };
    }

function decrypt(val){
    //method that just plays with the string passed in the parameter (val)
    return decryptedString;
}

/****************************************************************************/
/* 2. Data returned in the callback is an encrypted json from java servlet. */
/****************************************************************************/

// value from my input
var identifier = $('#txtid').val();

$.post('MyServlet', {identifier : identifier} , function(data) {

    // MyServlet returns 0 if no data, else returns an encrypted json as base64 generated with a key.
    if (data != 0) {

        // base64key() is a method from base64.js that just return a key (like b3NjYXJqY)
        var b = new base64key();

        // variable that contains encrypted json as string
        var temp = data.replace(b.key().substring(5), '');

        // decrypt the json (temp variable)
        var json = decrypt(temp).replace(b.key(), '');

        // parse the json string
        var info = JSON.parse(json);

        // fill the inputs with data
        $('#txtname').val(info.name);
        $('#txtemail').val(info.email);
        $('#txtphone').val(info.phone); 
});

/**********************************************************************************/
/* 3. Just to have an idea of the "data" structure, this is the decrypted json.   */
/**********************************************************************************/
{"name": "Oscar Jara", "email": "oscar@stackoverflow.com", "phone": "+45 88779900"}
```

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript code that runs the `$.post()` call, including the code that catches the user typing in the input?

Comment: Ok, I updated everything, please check.

Comment: I think the issue is comming from the JSON part because using web inspector with safari, it wasnt posible to recognize the JSON variable. Also, i found some articles regarding problems with JSON native method from javascript, maybe I will try json2.js or did anyone know any other? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question...

The problem was not the jQuery `POST`, the problem was `JSON` that is not compatible with some browsers at all, take a look at this:

http://caniuse.com/json

and I was facing an error with Safari and an error similar like this appeared "JSON variable wansn't able to be recognized" in the developer's console.

To solve this you need to use a library called `json2.js` that works really good.
Here you can find documentation and downloads:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js